# Print Kafka Stream Input out to console?

Tags: java, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've been looking through a lot of the Kafka documentation for a java application that I am working on. I've tried getting into the lambda syntax introduced in Java 8, but I am a little sketchy on that ground and don't feel too confident that it should be what I use as of yet.

I've a Kafka/Zookeeper Service running without any troubles, and what I want to do is write a small example program that based on the input will write it out, but not do a wordcount as there are so many examples of already.

As for sample data I will be getting a string of following structure:

## Example data

```
This a sample string containing some keywords such as GPS, GEO and maybe a little bit of ACC.
```

## Question

I want to be able to extract the 3 letter keywords and print them with a `System.out.println`. How do I get a string variable containing the input? I know how to apply regular expressions or even just searching through the string to get the keywords.

## Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "app_id");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9092");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_CONFIG, "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());

    final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();

    KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

    KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(stringSerde, stringSerde, "in-stream");

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, props);
    streams.start();

    //How do I assign the input from in-stream to the following variable?
    String variable = ?
}
```

I have zookeeper, kafka, producer and consumer running all hooked up to the same topic so I want to basically see the same `String` appear on all of the instances (producer, consumer and stream).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you use Kafka Streams, you need to apply functions/operators on your data streams. In your case, you create a `KStream` object, thus, you want to apply an operator to `source`.

Depending on what you want to do, there are operators that apply a function to each record in the stream independently (eg. `map()`), or other operators that apply a function to multiple record together (eg. `aggregateByKey()`). You should have a look into the documentation: http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html#kafka-streams-dsl and examples https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Thus, you never create local variables using Kafka Streams as you show in your example above, but rather embed everything in operators/functions that get chained together.

For example, if you want to print all input record to stdout, you could do

```
KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(stringSerde, stringSerde, "in-stream");
source.foreach(new ForeachAction<String, String>() {
    void apply(String key, String value) {
        System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
    }
 });
```

Thus, after you start your application via `streams.start()`, it will consumer the records from you input topic and for each record of your topic, a call to `apply(...)` is done, which prints the record on stdout.

Of course, a more native way for printing the stream to the console would be to use `source.print()` (which internally is basically the same as the shown `foreach()` operator with an already given `ForeachAction`.)

For your example with assigning the string to a local variable, you would need to put your code into `apply(...)` and do your regex-stuff etc. there to "extract the 3 letter keywords".

The best way to express this, would however be via a combination of `flatMapValues()` and `print()` (ie, `source.flatMapValues(...).print()`). `flatMapValues()` is called for each input record (in your case, I assume key will be `null` so you can ignore it). Within your `flatMapValue` function, you apply your regex and for each match, you add the match to a list of values that you finally return.

```
source.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
    @Override
    public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {
        ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();

        // apply regex to value and for each match add it to keywords

        return keywords;
    }
}
```

The output of `flatMapValues` will be a `KStream` again, containing a record for each found keyword (ie, the output stream is a "union" over all lists your return in `ValueMapper#apply()`). Finally, you just print your result to console via `print()`.
(Of course, you could also use a single `foreach` instead of `flatMapValue`+`print` but this would be less modular.)

Comment: Wow. Great answer mate. This is what I was looking for!

Comment: ')' missing at end of the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks @asitm9 ! Updated. Feel free to edit directly next time :)